# Does a "refused Schengen visa" application affect future Employment/Jobseeker visa applications?

Tags: schengen, germany

My wife and I have been thinking to move to Germany through employment for quite some time. However, we decided to visit Germany first as tourists, in order to get a better feeling about the country and the culture there. This would assure us that we are taking the right decision to move there permanently in future.

So, we recently applied for Schengen tourist visa through the German Embassy in Malaysia. It took them three weeks to process our application and the outcome was refusal of visa due to:

> - Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided.
> - You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of intended stay or for the return to the country of
>     origin or residence ...

I accept that I did not have enough funds in my bank account to assure them about my financial stability (I could have added more funds to my account if they had contacted me asking for that though).

Anyway! I decided to let go our decision for visiting Germany as a tourist and try to apply for Employment/Jobseeker visa this time. My concern is that our previous failed application for Schengen visa would affect our new application.

Can anyone give me some advice regarding our situation?

Comment: This question should be migrated to Expatriates.

Comment: Do not migrate.  It is already cross-posted.

Comment: @Karlson, should it be deleted here as off-topic?

Comment: Closed as off-topic and cross-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The visa officials in any Schengen country will be aware of your failed application, so that might *affect* their evaluation, but it won't *exclude* you from consideration.
- The best way to get an employment visa for Germany is to have a [well-paid job](http://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/Publikationen/Broschueren/bildung-und-beruf-in-deutschland.pdf). [Speaking German](http://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/DE/Publikationen/Broschueren/bildung-und-beruf-in-deutschland.pdf) helps, of course.
- Right now a large number of Syrian refugees are arriving in Germany. Immigration officials are working overtime.

Comment: The last point has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Niko, it *shouldn't* have anything to do with the question, but I guess it *will*.

Comment: Thank you @o.m. for your answer. However, my question was, whether or not my refused Schengen visa application affects negatively on my future employment/jobseeker visa? Or since the new application is in different category, they will process my application independent of my previous Schengen applications?

Comment: @asami, I think that was answered in my first and second bullet point. When you apply for a visa, the officials will evaluate both your new application and your previous record. With the old application, they were afraid that you're going to stay and work. Now you ask for the permission to do so, and there will be different requirements. Probably the easiest way is if a reputable employer in Germany hires you with an annual salary of more than 48400 EUR **before** you apply. (That's roughly 1.5 times the average salary in Germany.)

Comment: @asami, keep in mind that Germany is not **trying** to attract immigrants, with very few exceptions. Section 19a (university graduates with a job offer, especially in technical fields) should be easier than section 18c (jobseekers).